# Modal Issue with Layers

Tags: html, css, wordpress

http://designatwork.net/digitec/business-services/advisory/

When you click on Customer Login at the top, the modal comes up, but the header banner doesn't darken like the rest of the page does. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the higher [`z-index`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/z-index/) value which allows it to appear over the darkened background.

```
.blue {
    background-color: #00acc8;
    margin-top: -20px;
    min-height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 8888; /* Remove */
}
```

Comment: Welcome :) Next time please try to add related code. I know yours was a question with code that is big. But it allows to avoid down votes.